# Select columns that have more than 1 unique value

Tags: r

I currently have the following dataframe:

```
datnotformeanfill<-
  data.frame(b8=c(1,2,2,2,1,1),b7=rep(1,6),
             b6=c(6,2,3,3,6,3),b5=c(6,3,3,3,4,3),
             b4=c(rep(6,5),1),b3=rep(0,6),
             b2=rep(1,6),b1=c(2,2,2,2,1,1))

> datnotformeanfill
  b8 b7 b6 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1
1  1  1  6  6  6  0  1  2
2  2  1  2  3  6  0  1  2
3  2  1  3  3  6  0  1  2
4  2  1  3  3  6  0  1  2
5  1  1  6  4  6  0  1  1
6  1  1  3  3  1  0  1  1
```

I am trying to use a combination of the `which` and `unique` functions to return only the columns which have more than 1 unique value, but am not completely certain how to use these (or perhaps some other function(s)) to return the columns.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `Filter` with function `f = var`.  It will check the variance for each column.  If the column have only a single unique value, the variance will be '0'.  This will be converted back to logical 'FALSE/TRUE' and used for subsetting the dataset.

```
 Filter(var, datnotformeanfill)
 #    b8 b6 b5 b4 b1
 #  1  1  6  6  6  2
 #  2  2  2  3  6  2
 #  3  2  3  3  6  2
 #  4  2  3  3  6  2
 #  5  1  6  4  6  1
 #  6  1  3  3  1  1
```

Or another option is looping through the columns with `sapply` and check the condition whether the `length` of `unique` elements are greater than 1.  This returns a logical 'TRUE/FALSE' vector that can be used for subsetting as well.

```
datnotformeanfill[sapply(datnotformeanfill, function(x) length(unique(x))>1)]
```

Comment: Neither of those worked, could you please write them with the dataframe names I have specified to make sure I am filling them in correctly?  Thank you

Comment: @costebk08 It's just changing the object names.  It worked for me.  Updated

Comment: The `var` thing is ingenious. Would never think of it. Wonder if its fast though.

Comment: @DavidArenburg `Filter` is usually faster.  But, with large dataset with more columns, the `lapply` route may be more fast

Comment: `Filter` is pretty much an `lapply` wrapper. More or less equivalent to your second option

Comment: @akrun Thank you that worked, I admit I was confused and did not realize there was a `Filter` function as I was confusing it with the dplyr `filter` I will accept as soon as I can.  What does var do by the way?

Comment: @PierreLafortune it's not magic, it's just `as.logical(sapply(df, var))`. The good old convergence from logical to numeric and backwards in R

Comment: @costebk08 If there is only a single unique value the variance will be `0` and Filter converts it to `FALSE/TRUE` based on that and subset the dataset

Comment: @DavidArenburg Is there a more compact way with data.table other than this `setDT(d1)[, d1[,lapply(.SD, uniqueN)>1],with=FALSE]`

Comment: I was trying and couldn't get anything neater than that to work. @DavidArenburg is of course brevity king though...

Comment: Hmm... dunno, I don't have time to check right now, but I'm sure @Frank will have some nice idea.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

a tidy solution that also works for non-numeric columns:

```
library(dplyr)
datnotformeanfill %>%
   select_if(function(col) length(unique(col))>1)

  b8 b6 b5 b4 b1
1  1  6  6  6  2
2  2  2  3  6  2
3  2  3  3  6  2
4  2  3  3  6  2
5  1  6  4  6  1
6  1  3  3  1  1
```